# Easy way of engaging non-programmers (i.e. designers) into using version control?

Tags: version-control, teamwork

What are some key ways of getting your team involved in using version control during development, web development or otherwise?

I refuse to work without it, which means anyone involved in the project must also use it. It's just good practice.

GUIs like Tower have helped, but the concept of it is either met with anger ('not my job!' kinda attitude), timidness, or just straight up not using it (using FTP instead, circumventing version control for say, dev or deployment).

Edit: I should have clarified a little that I don't just mean images/PSDs.

Comment: Make it _EASY_ to use...

Comment: I find that Git is pretty easy once you spend a few days with it, and have a consensus on how development should go.. it's still been a bigger hurdle for others.

Comment: One bit to remember is that version control and backup sometimes meld (while vastly different) and to a designer with binary data; backing up may already be the norm and therefore understanding what he or she is gaining needs to be understood.

Comment: @Kevin:  What's easy, obvious, and intuitive to a programmer isn't necessarily anything of the sort to other people, even intelligent and creative other people.

Comment: Get engaged with a designer then engage her privately into versioning control. :)

Comment: This requires the same strategy that should be used for most every development practice that you want to be absolutely required on your team - sell it to your boss and get him to require it of his team.

Comment: I see your clarification - can you explain a little bit more how you want your designers and other members of the team to use version control?

Answer (score 12):

I work on a team of both developers and designers and we all use version control.  For the designers, it sucks.

**File sharing/backup does always equal Version Control**

When you say:

> I refuse to work without it, which means anyone involved in the project must also use it. It's just good practice.

You need to be aware of the pitfalls of using version control with binary data:

- **Overwriting**: If two designers are working on the same file, the second one to commit will overwrite the first's changes as the current version.  The only way to prevent this is locking or constant communication about who is doing what to which file, both of which can hamper their team's workflow.
- **Merging**: Tool-assisted merging is non-existent in binary data.  Manual merging is painful and prone to huge amounts of errors.
- **Repository bloating:** VC systems store only changed lines for text files.  This is not possible with binary data, since the whole file will look different to the VC system.  This means that while 20 versions of 10KB text file may only take up 20KB, 20 versions of a 1MB file will probably take up closer to 20MB.  A moderate-sized design team can easily generate many revisions on dozens of binary files.  Your IT department may soon hate you for the storage requirements and possibly even increased memory/CPU your VC server will have.

  You and other developers may also soon hate how long checkouts or updates may take unless you've set up a very good repository organization to avoid the binary files.
- **Reduced benefit**: Your designers will rarely, if ever, go back to previous versions of binary files, because 1) no easy way to check a past version's contents 2) no easy way to merge it anyway, and most importantly, 3) they don't work that way -- they are used to building alternate versions of some graphic that may still be useful into the production files themselves.

For your code, you should absolutely be using VC and you are right to demand it.

**But you need to check the assumption that that means *everyone* must also be using it,** as well as whether it's even good practice for designers (though backup is). You should store final graphic assets required by your web site/application in your VC, but for production files, it may not be the right solution.

Comment: Regarding the "repository bloat": you can try to work around that with the right file formats. Documentation stored in a [document markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_document_markup_languages) format and graphics stored in a [graphics markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vector_graphics_markup_languages) format instead of the equivalent binary formats can help a lot. Of course the viability of this depends on the project in question and the willingness and competence of the involved people. ;)

Comment: Overwriting doesn't happen on VCSs worth anything.  What happens is that you have two versions of the same file.  Yes, the HEAD of the repository will have the last save; but the other designer's work is _not lost_ like it would be on a shared hard drive.  I think that is an important distinction.

Comment: @Berin: That's true, but one of the benefits of modern VCS is that two people can work on the same thing at the same time and a lot of the reconciliation work is automatic. However, with a binary file where there is no meaningful merge process, that is not possible. Additionally, the head of the repository is the one that people will think of as "real".

Comment: As the lifecycle for source code and design documentation differs, make sure to use seprarate repositories for them. I don't agree that repositories suck for designers; most time is spent thinking and modelling, not making lots of small changes to documents. We also make it a rule to disallow automatic merging (on all files stored in the repositories) and therefore have mandatory file locking for edits. Combined with good team communication this prevents a lot of the drawbacks you mention.

Comment: @Berin Yes, that's definitely important to know that you can recover the files. What I'm talking about is  the lost time when one person tells the PM that their work should be there, when another designer committed right over the top of it and didn't realize it needed merging.  With typical *source code* VCs, it's not exactly intuitive in helping you realize that you are saving over someone's changes, not just over the previous version.  @rsp - That may very well depend on the job itself.  Our designers spend lots of time making small changes.

Comment: Some VCS are actually very efficient at detecting changes in binary data and storing them which makes them on par with text files as far as storing efficiency goes.  Of course this only address the bloating issue, others remain unchanged and are more fundamental.

Comment: You're quite wrong, e.g.: *Overwriting* - this in not a problem of version control, on the opposite, it helps you to detect it. *VC systems store only changed lines for text files.* - False for git.

Comment: @maaartinus - It may help you detect it, but that won't stop many people (who just don't know better) from just marking the problem resolved and committing. As for git, that's interesting, but what it does differently (use more space) for text files doesn't make the situation any better for binary files, which are still orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: @Renesis: OK, the other people may overwrite my work, using VC or not using it. But with git they'd need to say `--force` and even if they mindless do it, I'll be warned and never lose my version. While git stores each commit as a whole, it usually uses *less* space than svn, since it compresses each commit based on any data it already has. This works often quite well also for binary files, for example I have about 1 MB `*.doc` files and their whole history takes only 360 kB.

Comment: this phrase is awkward, reads like it has a typo _"File sharing/backup does always equal Version Control"_. Is there supposed to be a `not` in there?

Answer (score 5):

The way to approach this is to **setup a build system** (like [Hudson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29)) which uses the **version control system to retrieve the build sources** and make it a project rule that only **artefacts** that are a **delivered by the build system** are going to the test team and eventually deployed at the customer site.

Make it very clear that as far as the project process is concerned anything not coming from the build is private to the developers only; as long as someones' work is not accepted into the build, it might as well not exist.

Answer (score 4):

> I refuse to work without it, which means anyone involved in the project must also use it. It's just good practice.

That's a GREAT attitude, right up there with 'not my job!'  :-)

The best way of getting buy-in is using something like TortoiseGit or TortoiseSVN to integrate version control into Explorer (assuming Windows).  It takes time to see real benefit if you're not used to the version control paradigm.  Tortoise at least makes it easy to work with VCS with the mouse.  A simple "Right Click -> Checkin" is all it takes.

For this reason, I've been looking to implement transparent version control in TortoiseGit on every file close.  If you give someone a branch to work on, and then every write/close becomes a commit operation, then at some point you as the developer can merge their branch without worrying about the consistency of the entire repository, and they can get on with the business of doing what they do without having to know about version control.

I have this same problem with a huge set of audit documents that I can't get people to version control, so we have 50 versions of the same document floating around that are all subtly different.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrate the advantages:

- Show them how they can save time by allowing everyone to share work and access to a central location.
- Show them how it allows designers to work on different parts of the project at the same time and merge it back together.
- Show them how they can tag and build older version of an application for testing or troubleshooting.
- Show them how they can mess around with a design for experimentation and then refresh the project and not keep changes if they don't want.
- Show them how they can see what has happened over time.

Comment: -1 This was about engaging non-programmers; the list appears geared at a programmer. If you modify your answer I will certainly remove the down vote...

Comment: I think you missed the "for non-programmers" part.  All the tasks you mentioned are programmer tasks.

Comment: Sorry, I just read the question, not the title.  I will edit the answer.

Comment: 1 Removed...

Answer (score 1):

"Not my job" about version control is a sane attitude from a non-programmer.

Build a version control system as simple and invisible as Dropbox is for syncing or Time Machine for backup.

It should just work. No checkout, no commit. Just put the files in the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using tortoiseHG / mercurial with the new website lady, no problems there.  Having no checkouts makes it super simple and puts all the pressure on the person who actually has to make sure the files are synced up.  It doesn't even seem like "one more thing to do", it's just, "ok I'm going to demo the website so I've got to ask Peter to resync the changes." and that's no problem.

I had no experience with mercurial before, we use VSS and I would never have wished that on anyone for website source control.   I tried it once and I wouldn't blame anyone for not wanting to use it then.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use of of tortoise* clones, it is the simpler it get. Or integrate the version control, in the IDE or whatever.